# How do I remove a Hudson Upstream Project relation?

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I used to have one job, which I split into two. For some reason, the new split-off job treats the first as an Upstream Project. I'd like to remove this relation, but can't find the configuration for it on disk, or in the Hudson UI (ver. 1.312)

Note: the new job, like the old one, is maven2. There is no reference/relation between the POMs at all.

How can I remove the Upstream Project relation, or at least find where it is declared on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where it's stored on disk, but you should see text fields for both upstream and downstream relations in the project configuration screen.

Downstream:
[image: downstream]
<sub>(source: [pixor.net](http://pixor.net/temp/skitch/crux_Config_%5BHudson%5D-20091215-121023.jpg))</sub>

Upstream:
[image]
<sub>(source: [pixor.net](http://pixor.net/temp/skitch/crux-testsuite-perl_Config_%5BHudson%5D-20091215-121112.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Do you know which section it is supposed to be under? I'm on the configure screen for each job, and definitely not seeing those fields :/

Comment: Interestingly, those fields for both upstream and downstream are blank! However, "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" was checked, and even though my POM has 0 dependencies in it, unchecking that option cleared the bogus relation. Thanks for spurring me into the right direction, hope whoever might read this comment finds your answer and my notes useful.

Comment: Could you please edit this answer to stand alone without the images? As you can see, the images are dead right now.

Answer (score 8):

I am new to hudson and have the task of scheduling our builds. I had the same situation, project relationship between Parent Project A and 3 Child projects, upstream and downstream trigger fields are blank in the configs. Thanks to Aaron, unchecked the "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built". Realized that have to uncheck this in Parent Project A config and each of the Child projects for the project relationships to go away.

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins,When you have projects that depend on each other, Jenkins can track which build of the upstream project is used by which build of the downstream project, by using the records created by the fingerprint support.

For this feature to work, the following conditions need to be met:

The upstream project records the fingerprints of its build artifacts
The downstream project records the fingerprints of the upstream files it uses
This allows Jenkins to correlate two projects.

Because of this, the upstream and downstream might be created automatically. So, in the project configuration, uncheck the option

```
Build Triggers
```

**Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built**

This will remove all the upstream downstream that are existing even after deleting the streaming dependency explicitly.