# Hudson Downstream Projects Not Listing Upstream Dependencies

Tags: java, hudson, build-dependencies

I have an upstream project (dao) and a downstream consumer (scb). I would like to configure it so that when scb is built, the build summary page (after clicking on a build number) will show "Upstream builds: dao #blah".

How do I do this? Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910022/how-do-i-remove-a-hudson-upstream-project-relation), I already have scb configured to:

- Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built
- Build after other projects are built (dao)

I also have the dao project configured to build via "Build other projects," although ideally, I don't want to trigger the build; I just want scb to show me which build of dao it used as an upstream project.

If it helps, these are both Spring/Hibernate Java projects that each build a single JAR file; the dao project is a group of common DAO classes.

To be clear what I'm talking about, Hudson has a **project relationship link.** This link *used* to show a connection between certain builds of dao and certain builds of scb. (I wish it would do that for all the new builds, but it stopped.) I want this data to be populated. (I presume this is the same as showing upstream/downstream in the build-version screen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the same question you referenced in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910022/how-do-i-remove-a-hudson-upstream-project-relation). Configure the **Build Trigger* section for **Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built**, and viola.

Also, it's critical that **the down-stream builds complete and are successful.** Builds that fail or failed tests will *not* trigger downstream builds.

I know you've seen that they *have* on your system, but that's downright strange.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question. Found

> Multiple upstream builds can be aggregated into one downstream build, so generally speaking you cannot figure out which build it was.

On [OS Dir MailingList](http://osdir.com/ml/java.hudson.user/2007-08/msg00300.html)

Comment: I only have one upstream build that goes into three downstream builds. I don't see why this should be impossible.

Comment: on your case it might be only one but in general it cannot be determined (according to the link)

Comment: I've seen cases for different related projects where it DOES show this on a build level. That's why I know it's possible.